# Error while importing data from Mysql to Hbase using sqoop

Tags: mysql, hbase, sqoop

I am trying to import data from Mysql to Hbase using sqoop.
I am running following command.

`sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost/database --table users --columns "loginid,email" --username tester -P -m 8 --hbase-table hbaseTable --hbase-row-key user_id --column-family user_info --hbase-create-table`

But i am getting below error :-

> 13/05/08 10:42:10 WARN hbase.ToStringPutTransformer: Could not insert
>   row with null value for row-key column: user_id

please help here

Comment: Did you check that your user_ID doesn't have Null value?

Comment: Yes .. I checked .. user_id is primary key in my table. All rows have a value for it.

Comment: one strange thing i noticed  - when i dont specify "--columns" options , above command works just fine.But i need this option in order to have multiple column families in my hbase table.I will issue above command multiple times , each time for a different column family and set of columns.

Comment: Somebody please reply.

Answer (score 2):

Got the solution.
I was not including my rowKey i.e. user_id in the columns list.
After including it , it worked like a charm.
Thanks..

Comment: I'm having the same issue as you but adding or removing  --column yields the same issue

Answer (score 1):

Your columns should be upper status, not `seq_id` but `SEQ_ID`.

I think sqoop considering it as a different column.which is null(Of course).